# How do you debug C code that works in the debugger?

Tags: c, gdb, initialization, lldb

I have the following C code

```
double ComputeWord (String* word, List* dict, List* words, Matrix* results, String* ret) {
    int i = 0;
    signed long wordIndex = ListFind (words, (void*)word);
    double min = StringSize (word); // Largest possible cost
    int minIndex = 0;
    if (wordIndex == ListEnd (words) ) { 
        ListAppend(words, (void*) word);
        wordIndex = ListSize(words) - 1;
        MatrixExpand (results, 0, ListSize(words));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ListSize(dict); i++) {
        if (!strcmp (CString(word), CString( (String*)ListElement(dict, i) ) ) ) { min = 0; minIndex = i; break; }
        double current = fromDatabase ((long)MatrixElement(results, i, wordIndex) );
        if (current == 0) {
            printf ("Was not processed\n");
            current = lDist (word, ListElement(dict, i) );
            MatrixSetElement (results, (void*)toDatabase(current), i, wordIndex);
        }
        if (current <= min) { min = current; minIndex = i; }
        printf ("%s to %s - %.1lf\n", word->elementArray, ((String*)ListElement (dict,     i))->elementArray, current);
    }

    String temp;
    StringInit (&temp);
    char temp2[256];

    sprintf (temp2, ",%.1lf", min);

    StringSet (&temp, temp2);

    StringConcatenate(ret, (String*) ListElement (dict, minIndex) );
    StringConcatenate(ret, &temp);

    StringDelete (&temp);
    StringAppend(ret, ' ');
    printf ("matched %s to %s - %.1lf\n", word->elementArray, ((String*)ListElement (dict, minIndex))->elementArray, min);
    return min;
}
```

What it does is it takes a dictionary dict and a word and tries to match the word in the dictionary using demerau-levenshtein distance (lDist), then stores the result in a matrix.

What's happening is that while my algorithm calculates the distance correctly, it thinks that some of the words are already stored, so it gets an incorrect .
I tried opening GDB to try and figure out what was going on but the program runs correctly in it.

The results I am getting are these:

```
creating dictionary
adding aspecto to dict
adding matematica to dict
adding algebra to dict
adding posicao to dict
adding profissao to dict
adding fourier to dict
adding casa to dict
adding calculo to dict
adding dificil to dict
Was not processed
aepscto to aspecto - 3.0
Was not processed
aepscto to matematica - 9.5
Was not processed
aepscto to algebra - 8.5
Was not processed
aepscto to posicao - 5.5
Was not processed
aepscto to profissao - 9.0
Was not processed
aepscto to fourier - 10.5
Was not processed
aepscto to casa - 6.5
Was not processed
aepscto to calculo - 7.0
Was not processed
aepscto to dificil - 9.0
matched aepscto to aspecto - 3.0
Was not processed
caculo to aspecto - 6.5
Was not processed
caculo to matematica - 11.0
Was not processed
caculo to algebra - 8.5
Was not processed
caculo to posicao - 7.0
Was not processed
caculo to profissao - 10.5
Was not processed
caculo to fourier - 9.0
Was not processed
caculo to casa - 5.0
Was not processed
caculo to calculo - 1.0
Was not processed
caculo to dificil - 7.5
matched caculo to calculo - 1.0
Was not processed
matmatica to aspecto - 10.0
Was not processed
matmatica to matematica - 1.0
Was not processed
matmatica to algebra - 9.5
Was not processed
matmatica to posicao - 8.5
Was not processed
matmatica to profissao - 11.5
Was not processed
matmatica to fourier - 11.0
Was not processed
matmatica to casa - 8.0
Was not processed
matmatica to calculo - 10.5
Was not processed
matmatica to dificil - 10.0
matched matmatica to matematica - 1.0
augebra to aspecto - 6.5
augebra to matematica - 11.0
augebra to algebra - 8.5
augebra to posicao - 7.0
augebra to profissao - 10.5
augebra to fourier - 9.0
augebra to casa - 5.0
augebra to calculo - 1.0
augebra to dificil - 7.5
matched augebra to calculo - 1.0
```

I noticed that the results for "augebra" are exactly the same as for "caculo", which means that ListFind is returning the index for "caculo", but that should be impossible since i'm straight up using strcmp for that.

```
/* Method: StringListComp
 * Parameters:
 * a - First String
 * b - Second String
 * Return value:
 * a == b
 * Description:
 * A specialization of list compare for strings. Compares the strings and returns.
 */

Bool StringListCompare (void* a, void* b) {
    return (Bool)!strcmp ( ( (String*)a)->elementArray, ( (String*)b)->elementArray);
}


/* Method: ListFind                                                                                                                                                                                         
 * Parameters:
 * list - List to search
 * element - Element to find
 * Return value:
 * Returns element if it was found and ListEnd if not.
 * Description:
 * Search list for element.
 */

uintptr_t ListFind (List* list, void* element) {
    uintptr_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < list->size; i++) {
        if ( list->ListCompare(list->elementArray[i], element) ) return i;
    }
    return ListEnd (list);
}
```

How is this possible?

EDIT:
I think i might have found the issue.

When i invoke the method like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < ListSize(&workingStudent); i++) {
        score += ComputeWord (ListElement(&workingStudent, i), &dict, &words, &results, &ret);
        StringDelete ((String*)ListElement (&workingStudent, i);
    }
```

What happens is I am deleting the string that I am sending to the list on the line

```
ListAppend(words, (void*) word);
```

Since word is a pointer, the string gets deleted and the list doesn't know.
That way, the char* in String starts pointing to a free memory position which can be changed.

Comment: Any compiler warnings ? Have you tried running under valgrind ?

Comment: Have you tried adding some `printf` statements? To check the values of your variables?

Comment: No compiler warnings, Valgrind doesn't work on mac and i have added printf statements where i thought the bug might be. No luck whatsoever.

Comment: To add to above comments, make sure to do a clean build after enabling compiler warnings. Actually, whenever there are mysterious problems, first try clean build.

Comment: Just install a Linux VM. It's well worth the trouble of getting access to valgrind (if you can't find similar tool for Mac).

Comment: And one more thing, add asserts liberally. They have the double purpose of catching invalid state early, and documenting how your code is supposed to work.

Comment: Instead of Valgrind one can use the AddressSanatizer and/or MemorySanatizer. They are part of recent Clang and GCC.

Comment: Done all of those things. I always compile with -Wall and i have my own exception throwing thing in the code. Also tried make clean.

Comment: I think i might have found the issue. I'll update the question.

Comment: Note that `-Wall` is still pretty liberal. For *gcc* (also *clang*? not sure), add `-Wextra`, and possibly `-Wconversion` if you want to be sure your code is portable and doesn't break for values where most significant bit is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was happening was the debugger doesn't allow changes to freed memory, so it was keeping the deleted word fresh. This is not true for real world memory though.
The fix to this was to remove the line that was deleting the string and add this to the code:

```
if (wordIndex == ListEnd (words) ) { 
    ListAppend(words, (void*) word);
    wordIndex = ListSize(words) - 1;
    MatrixExpand (results, 0, ListSize(words));
//==========\/This\/==========//
} else {
    StringDelete (word);
    free (word);
    word = (String*) ListElement (words, wordIndex);
}
```

So word gets deleted when it is unnecessary and starts pointing to the already cached word.
BEWARE of debuggers and their unnecessary correctness of data.